# How to get a specific array inside laravel collection

Tags: php, laravel, collections

I do have the collection below:

```
Collection {#265 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => array:9 [▼
      "dueDate" => "2017-10-29"
      "date" => "2017-09-29"
      "number" => "9030001"
      "statuse" => "Reminder"
      "currentCode" => "S"
      "amount" => 2006.0
      "remainingAmount" => 2006.0
      "convertedToAccountNumber" => null
      "originalCreditorReference" => "0903"
    ]
    1 => array:9 [▼
      "dueDate" => "2017-10-29"
      "date" => "2017-09-29"
      "number" => "9030022"
      "statuse" => "Reminder"
      "currentCode" => "S"
      "amount" => 2294.0
      "remainingAmount" => 2294.0
      "convertedToAccountNumber" => null
      "originalCreditorReference" => "0903"
    ]
    2 => array:9 [▼
      "dueDate" => "2017-11-01"
      "date" => "2017-10-02"
      "number" => "9040023"
      "statuse" => "Unpaid"
      "currentCode" => "S"
      "amount" => 3643.0
      "remainingAmount" => 3643.0
      "convertedToAccountNumber" => null
      "originalCreditorReference" => "0904"
    ]
  ]
}
```

My question is except iterating with a foreach loop is there any way getting a specific array inside this collection based on number key example I want to get back the array where number is equal to 9040023?

note. I did it using a foreach but I want to use laravel collection instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `where` method:

```
$collection->where('number', 9040023)->all();
```

Comment: Note: Its working except I don't need all() or get() :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use collection Helper Method (also Eloquent) : `flatMap`

> The flatMap method iterates through the collection and passes each
>   value to the given callback. The callback is free to modify the item
>   and return it, thus forming a new collection of modified items. Then,
>   the array is flattened by a level (using collapse() collection
>   method).

```
$collection->flatMap(function ($item){
    if ($item['number'] === "9040023"){
        return $item;
    }
});
```